# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Posts#edit No route matches {:action=>"show"

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, routes, form-for

I have been stuck with this issue for too long now - so hoping someone might be able to tell me what I am doing wrong. I am trying to add a simple blog to my website, using rails ajax through the remote: true option - everything works fine apart from editing a post.

Everything has been generated via the scaffold command and I am under the impression that it actually should be working.

As mentioned, what does not work is the editing of a post.

Error that is returned:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Posts#edit

Showing ~/webapp-rails4/app/views/posts/_form.html.erb where line #2 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :locale=>#<Post id: 6, title: "blog post nummer 2", body: "så prøver vi igen", created_at: "2014-11-02 11:42:19", updated_at: "2014-11-02 11:42:19", image: "Sk_rmbillede_2014-06-23_kl._21.31.58.png">, :id=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:locale, :id]

1: <% logger.debug 'form being rendered'%>
2: <%= form_for @post, remote: true do |f| %>
3:   
4: 
5:   <div class="field">
app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:2:in _app_views_posts__form_html_erb__3358809483585932967_70366784059520'
app/views/posts/edit.js.erb:2:in _app_views_posts_edit_js_erb___2360131588799055390_70366783957680'
```

my edit link:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post.id, locale: I18n.locale), remote: true %>
```

controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :js, :html

def edit
  logger.debug 'controller action edit'
  respond_with(@post)
end

def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  @post.save
  #respond_with(@post)
end

def update
  @post.update(post_params)
  #respond_with(@post)
end

private
  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :image)
  end
```

edit.js.erb (I have tried multiple things here, this is what I have at the moment):

```
alert('this is edit.js.erb');
$('#post<%= @post.id %> #editPostModal').append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'form', object: @post) %>");
$('#post<%= @post.id %> #editPostModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
```

_form.html.erb(seems to be what is throwing the error):

```
<% logger.debug 'form being rendered'%>
<%= form_for @post, remote: true, :multipart => true, authenticity_token: true do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :title %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :body %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
</div>
<div>
  <%= f.label :remote_image_url, "or image URL" %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :remote_image_url %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

rake routes:

```
posts       GET    /:locale/posts(.:format)           posts#index {:locale=>/en|dk/}
            POST   /:locale/posts(.:format)           posts#create {:locale=>/en|dk/}
new_post    GET    /:locale/posts/new(.:format)       posts#new {:locale=>/en|dk/}
edit_post   GET    /:locale/posts/:id/edit(.:format)  posts#edit {:locale=>/en|dk/}
post        GET    /:locale/posts/:id(.:format)       posts#show {:locale=>/en|dk/}
            PATCH  /:locale/posts/:id(.:format)       posts#update {:locale=>/en|dk/}
            PUT    /:locale/posts/:id(.:format)       posts#update {:locale=>/en|dk/}
            DELETE /:locale/posts/:id(.:format)       posts#destroy {:locale=>/en|dk/}
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the url for the form? `<%= form_for @post, url: edit_post_path(post.id, locale: I18n.locale), etc.`

Comment: you need to take care of your locale parameter, i don't know if this works `form_for [:en, @post]`

Comment: it might also be an issue with your default_url_options, you'll probably want to have the session locale passed by default?

Comment: @ptd - this for is expected to work for both create and edit, its a standard scaffold I have used...

Comment: @phoet yes - the locale should already be passed as default, i think this should handle that in my routes:


scope '/:locale' , :locale => /en|dk/ do

    resources :posts

Comment: @Christian no, you need to add it to the default_url_options like it's described here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params